# Change Listview Row back color C#

Tags: c#, listview

How can i change the back color of a listView for a particular value of sub items? I have a column for status and i want to change the back color of all "ACTIVE" to yellow.

Comment: how can i call it in the form load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want access to the `SubItems` of an entry. On a non virtual list view this would go something like this:

```
foreach(ListViewItem lvi in listView1)
{
    if(lvi.SubItems[colToCheck].Text == "ACTIVE")
    {
        lvi.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
}
```

Put this somewhere where the list is already filled. Since you mentioned the form load in your comment I suppose there is a method present that fills the ListView with items. Put the above snippet afterwards.

If you have a virtual list, check the corresponding item property in `RetrieveVirtualItem`:

```
  private void listView1_RetrieveVirtualItem(object sender, RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs e)
  {
      var lvi = GenerateListViewItemFromTheStore(e.ItemIndex);
      if (lvi != null)
      {
          if (lvi.SubItems[colToCheck].Text == "ACTIVE")
              lvi.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
      }
      else
          e.Item = new ListViewItem();
  }
```

In both snippets `colToCheck`is the column index of the column to check for Text equalling *ACTIVE*.